# border for div element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give border radius to a div **box** in javascript as i have give in 
css as border:2px solid #000;

How can i give it inside the for loop given below.

```js
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor="#ff33ff";
}
```

Comment: `elements[i].style.borderRadius = ...`

Comment: @phil elements[i].style.borderRadius = "2px  solid #000";  didn't produce the output

Comment: That's because `2px solid #000` is a `border` specification, not a `border-radius` one. I recommend reading the documentation ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can do it by :

```
object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"
```

Like this:

```
elements[i].style.borderRadius = "25px";
```